# How do I exclusively calculate the length of a response entity X only if it is a list and not dictionary or tuple?

Tags: python

```
print type(az.data.name) 
print len(az.data)  
print az.data
```

Prints:

```
type 'unicode'

51

X(entitledBlueprint=[], referenceId=u'2c918086646ed9e10164ac7be477298c', lastUpdateUser=u'admin', createdBy=u'admin', lockVersion=1, securityGroupId=None, imagePassword=u'password-hidden', imageId=u'qakvm12cluster', inactive=False, createUser=u'admin', owner=X(username=None, firstname=None, deleted=None, lastname=None, inactive=None, id=u'402881834d9ee4d1014d9ee5d73f0014'), quotaPolicyPks=[], vmQuota=None, id=u'2c918086646ed9e10164ac7bf0b92990', networkId=u'', capacity=None, hardwareId=u'datastore_sda13', lastModifiedBy=u'admin', groupName=None, referenceName=None, entitlementType=None, email=None, sizeLimit=None, username=u'', leaseTime=u'', entitledUsersPks=[], entitledBlueprintPks=[], deleted=False, lastModifiedDate=None, vlanId=None, quotaPolicies=[], blueprintEntitlementType=None, usageStats=None, lastUpdated=1531902161081L, accountType=u'AVAILABILITY_ZONE', createdDate=None, password=u'password-hidden', tenant=X(deleted=None, inactive=None, id=u'402881834d9ee4d1014d9ee5d73f0010', name=None), name=u'AZ_YQ0J', created=1531902161081L, url=u'', region=u'qakvm13dc', tenantPk=u'402881834d9ee4d1014d9ee5d73f0010', freeFormEntitlement=True, approvalEnforced=None, entitledUserGroups=[], entitledGroupsPks=[], ownerPk=u'402881834d9ee4d1014d9ee5d73f0014', entitledUsers=[], imageUsername=None, opts=None)
```

Comment: What do you want `len` to do otherwise? Can you supply a **[mcve]**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inbuilt function `isinstance` returns a bool if obj matches criteria

```
if isinstance([], list):
    print('I am a list')
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
if type(az.data)==list:
     length=len(az.data)
```

don't mention the list in ''/"" like 'list'. then it will become a string.

```
type([any list])
```

will return  type/class (type in 2.x and class in 3.x) its not string